# d3 vertical bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

How can I draw chart like this?
I have data (for example):

```
{
  "USA": {
    "value": 10,
    "companies": [ "Apple", "Google" ],
    "color": "red"
  },
  "Germany": {
    "value": 3,
    "companies": [ "SAP" ],
    "color": "green"
  }
}
```

"value" is for the left side.
"companies" is for the right side.
"value" != "compnaies" length.

I can't figure out what kind of graph I must use.
I'll try [hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy), but it must have only one root.

[image: graph]

Comment: This is a very interesting question! The chart can be made without any hierarchy. Unfortunately, it's *too broad* for S.O. Besides that, it will take a lot of code, and I doubt anyone here will make it for free (I mean, I won't). Good luck, though.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I just want to give me direction, in any case, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

i made a small poc but i'm not sure what you want so i can't really got much further please take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/z9bcfdvk/
i used the dataser you provided and added one entry:
Let me know if you want more detail.

```
var data = [
        {
            country: "USA",
            "value": 10,
            companies: ["Apple", "Google"],
            "color": "#123445"
        },
        {
            country: "Germany",
            "value":
                3,
            companies:
                ["SAP"],
            "color":
                "#987456"
        }, {
            country: "France",
            "value":
                1,
            companies:
                ["RENAULT"],
            "color":
                "#8b9838"
        }
    ]
```